# Returning member methods overloads by reference or not

Tags: c++, oop

So I saw a video talking about operator overloads in a class. This class was a fictitious `Number` class which instantiated real numbers and could be used like this `Number first(1)` or `Number second(2)` (numbers are stored in a num data member) and then we overloaded the operators as member methods , to be able to do this `first + second` or `-first`. The code for these operator overloads looked like this:

PS: `rhs` for right hand side

```cpp
Number &Number::operator+(const Number &rhs) {
   //perform math calculation between both objects
   return *this;  //return lhs by reference
}
```

or this for the unary minus operator which just returns the minus version of a single integer (useless but used as an example):

```cpp
Number operator-() {
   int temp = -num;
   return temp;//temporary
}
```

Now the video said that we should return an object by reference if it was used in a chain operations after it has gone throught the overload, I also heard it depends of the performance (is it to avoid copying?), but after that I'm still unsure when to return an object by reference or not in class operator overloads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the full implementation of `operator+`?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/6639989) you can find a really good explanation about operator overloading general rules.  In general, the return type shouldn't depend on whether the operator is overloaded as a member or a non member function. In these specific cases, the `operator+` and `operator-` should return by value, as they should return a new value instead of modifying the object they are called with.

Comment: Binary non-assigning operations usually should not return a reference, they also usually are const, not modfying their arguments. You binary plus in `a+b` would modify `a` and return it. That's a strategy for `operator+=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either call the overloaded operator, as either:

1. Binary Arithmetic Operation: Call an overloaded operator function directly in the same way an ordinary function is called:

   ```
   number1 + number2;              // normal expression
   operator+(number1, number2);    // equivalent function call
   ```

   In this case, both calls are equivalent. Both call the nonmember function `operator+`, passing `number1` as the first argument and `number2` as the second.
   The binary arithmetic operation doesn't modify either operand - it actually returns a new value from the two arguments. Hence you dont return a reference.
2. Compound Assignment Operation: The other option is to call the member operator function explicitly:

   ```
   number1 += number2;             // expression-based call
   number1.operator+=(number2);    // equivalent call to a member operator function
   ```

   Here, both the statements, call the member function `operator+=`, binding `this` to the address of `number1` and passing `number2` as an argument. Hence you return it as a reference.

   ```
   Number& operator+=(const Number& rhs) // compound assignment
   {                          
       /* addition of rhs to *this takes place here */
       return *this; // return the result by reference
   }
   ```

Comment: Thnak you for your answer, however I still don'T understand why I have to return the object by reference in the second example.

Comment: Well, the compound assignment operator allows for chaining. So, to perfrom operations such as `(number1 += 1) += 2;`, you need to return the object as reference, because the operation is performed, over and over again on the same object `number1`. If this wasn't returned by reference, then the operation wouldn't be performed on the same object. So, to sum it up, to have consistency with the built-in compound assignment, these operators should return a reference to their left-hand operand.